# Can i access env variables in Exception Handler

Tags: php, laravel, null, environment-variables

I need to get constants in `.env` file in `Exception/Handler.php`,

I have change my **Handle.php**

```
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if (env('APP_DEBUG')) {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    } else {
        return response(view('error_custom')->render(),200);
    }
}
```

and **env('APP_DEBUG') return null**, any ideas?

Comment: That should work fine. However, it is recommended to use the `config` values as these get cached. `config('app.debug')`

Comment: Which laravel version you are using? That should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
    As you know you have debug variable in env something like the below:
    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false);
    Laravel 5+:
    then you can access it like $debug = config('app.debug');
    Laravel 4.2:
    $debug = Config::get('app.debug');
    but before going further just check you get the value for it, if you have set value of APP_DEBUG as false in env then you will get 0 but you can't see it while printing so create a condition such as
    if (config('app.debug')) {
      echo "Yes";
    } else {
      echo "No";
    }

once you get the output you are ready to go further.
```